# Laravel load database

Tags: database, laravel, dynamic

I am working in a Laravel application where there is a database that changes over time,

it might be called

```
 20042018
```

today and

```
  21042018
```

tomorrow 
I know how to calculate its name, I just don't know where to add the script to find the db name.

Must I do this in a modal? or is there a constructor somewhere where I am supposed to set a dynamic DB?

In my database.php file, I want to include this DB., but how can I dynamically add this database to my driver in database.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could set in your `AppServiceProvider.php` register function:

```
public function register()
{
     $db = 2104018; // calculate the name

     config(['database.connections.mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => config('database.connections.mysql.host'),
        'database'  => $db,
        'username'  => config('database.connections.mysql.username'),
        'password'  => config('database.connections.mysql.password'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ]]);
}
```

Or another way would be to create a helper function in `app/helpers.php`, add it to your `composer.json` under `"autoload": { "files": ["app/helpers.php"] }` and call it from the `database.php` config file:

```
// app/helpers.php
if (!function_exists('calculate_db_name')) {
    function calculate_db_name() {
        $db = 12345; // do the thing...
        return $db;
    }
}

// config/database.php
'mysql' => [
    ...
    'database' => calculate_db_name()
    ...
]
```

Comment: This is a nice and elegant solution!

Comment: Agreed, it's a pretty common approach for multi tenant apps that needs to switch the database connection based on an active user id, although it's usually done in middleware.

Comment: Quick question, what is the impact of using `env()` in the code base instead of accessing by `config()` especially when caching your config files for production usage?

Comment: Bad things can happen. Calls to `env()` not within config files will return null after `php artisan cache:config` is ran. All config files are compiled into one for quick loading. Full disclosure, I copy pasted this from the `config/database.php` file without thinking twice of it, I will update the answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.